# Looking to build myself a tiny, free VMWare image for PHP+MySQL Development

Tags: php, mysql, vmware

I'm looking to build myself a VMWare image for PHP+MySQL Development.

At present I'm using an ubuntu image which takes ~1 GB of my hard drive space. I'm looking to replace it with something smaller and lighter.

So, I'm curious... What do you folks use? It doesn't matter what OS / webserver as long as it's running Php 5 and MySQL. The smaller and lighter the better.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget [Slax](http://www.slax.org/). Build your own compressed distribution with only what you want. It works well in a virtual machine.

Comment: Wiki Slax: "A live CD which aims to provide a complete desktop for general use. Permanent installation of Slax is not recommended or supported; it is designed for "live" use only. Also can be run from a USB flash drive."

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [jeos](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos) - you can probably half the install size while sticking with Ubuntu. And I guess you should be able to create one with the standard server CD?

Comment: Wow, this looks impressive. Thanks for the link.

Comment: you could also have a look the vmware site. they have a lot of complete vm's downloadable.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to squeeze the size, a basic Debian system should be able to fit into 250MB. You just have to take care that you unselect the "standard" set of packages while installing. Adding [lighttp](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/lighttpd) (approx. 1MB) and php5(-cgi ?) should only add marginally to the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Debian Etch Mini](http://www.visoracle.com/download/debian/), it is only 332 MB. Please note that you may have to `apt-get dist-upgrade` to lenny if you need new versions of packages.

Answer (score 2):

Damn Small Linux can be configured pretty small. Other suggestions would be Debian and Gentoo.

Comment: If you installed Gentoo you (theoretically) only need to "sudo emerge -va php mysql apache" and you have a working server without the overhead of X etc.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to look at Tiny Core Linux.  I've built a Rebol webserver (cheyenne) image in about 15MB (including the OS).

http://www.tinycorelinux.com/

Thanks!
gb

Answer (score 1):

There is this image http://yii.googlecode.com/files/yii-vmware-1.0.6.zip that contains php 5.2.3, postgresql, lighttpd. It is pretty small, about 17MB download, it was built using buildroot.uclibc.org

Answer (score 0):

I know you said a VMWare image, but just thought I would let you know about [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

They have GNU/Linux, Windows & Mac Versions. From the website (Windows Version)

> The distribution for Windows 98, NT, 2000, 2003, XP and Vista. This version contains: Apache, MySQL, PHP + PEAR, Perl, mod_php, mod_perl, mod_ssl, OpenSSL, phpMyAdmin, Webalizer, Mercury Mail Transport System for Win32 and NetWare Systems v3.32, Ming, JpGraph, FileZilla FTP Server, mcrypt, eAccelerator, SQLite, and WEB-DAV + mod_auth_mysql.

Full Windows version is ~35Mb download. Again, sorry if this does not meet your exact needs, but may contain some useful information for you.

Comment: I'm sort-of looking for a vm ;) .

Answer (score 0):

From the asker:

[Slax](http://www.slax.org/) is the one I settled for; because it fit my needs. It's a very customizable boot-from cd linux distribution. Means that I can maintain several virtual machines which boot from the same iso image but have different states.

.

A couple of the other suggestions I thought were great:

[DSL](http://damnsmalllinux.org/) : is a nice timy platform: a ready vmware image is avalable for download. Just over 50 MB. I didn't try installing xampp over it, but it should be easy enough.

[jeos](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos): looks great as well, but there's no pre-existing vmware image... which is why I didn't use it myself

The debian net-install was also a tiny and great candidate. [Thoughtpolice](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/) has this and several other linux vmware images for ready download.

.

Also there are three *ready* {x}amp images also available at the bottom of this page: http://www.fosstools.org/ ; If you're looking for an image with no additional configuration required.